# Evaluating changes in between-individual variation in time series data

Tags: regression, time-series, logistic, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm working on evaluating an intervention using an interrupted time series approach, and one of our hypotheses involves evaluating its effect on between-individual variation. I'm using `lme4` to fit models for the aggregated binomial outcomes we are looking at, and I figured that one approach would be to fit separate random intercepts for the pre- and post-intervention periods and compare the standard deviations of the random effects, perhaps with some bootstrapping to generate CIs around the difference, along the lines of the reprex below:

```
n_ind = 50
n_t = 40

df <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(id = 1:n_ind,
            t = 1:n_t))

df$treat <- factor(ifelse(df$t>=n_t/2,"Post","Pre"),
                   levels = c("Pre","Post"))

# Doesn't make sense that pre/post levels aren't correlated, but I don't think it matters for this example?
prob_treat <- rbinom(n_ind,200,0.8) / 200
prob_untreat <- rbinom(n_ind,50,0.8) / 50


df$true <- ifelse(df$treat == "Post",
                  prob_treat[df$id],
              prob_untreat[df$id])

df$evals = 100

df$pos <- rbinom(nrow(df),df$evals,df$true) # Add some noise

plot(df$t,df$pos)

library(lme4)

fit <- glmer(cbind(pos,evals) ~ treat + (0+treat|id), data = df,family = "binomial")
summary(fit)

summ <- function(.) {
  vc <- sqrt(unlist(VarCorr(.)))[c(1,4)]
  vc[3] <- vc[1]-vc[2]
  names(vc) <- c("Pre","Post","Diff")
  return(vc)
}

t <- bootMer(fit,summ,nsim = 100) # Low for testing
confint(t)
```

I reckon that one issue with this approach in the context of binomial outcomes would be that intervention effects (e.g. changes in the overall probability of the outcome occurring) could also impact the standard deviation of the random effects. Is there some way to account for this? Or perhaps there is a simpler method to evaluate changes in between-individual variation that I'm missing?